# How to remove invalid code points from a string?

Tags: c#, unicode

I have a routine that needs to be supplied with normalized strings.  However, the data that's coming in isn't necessarily clean, and String.Normalize() raises ArgumentException if the string contains invalid code points.

What I'd like to do is just replace those code points with a throwaway character such as '?'.  But to do that I need an efficient way to search through the string to find them in the first place.  What is a good way to do that?

The following code works, but it's basically using try/catch as a crude if-statement so performance is terrible.  I'm just sharing it to illustrate the behavior I'm looking for:

```
private static string ReplaceInvalidCodePoints(string aString, string replacement)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder(aString.Length);
    var enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(aString);

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        string nextElement;
        try { nextElement = enumerator.GetTextElement().Normalize(); }
        catch (ArgumentException) { nextElement = replacement; }
        builder.Append(nextElement);
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

(edit:) I'm thinking converting the text to UTF-32 so that I could quickly iterate over it and see if each dword corresponds to a valid code point.  Is there a function that will do that?  If not, is there a list of invalid ranges floating around out there?

Comment: Note that, because of surrogate pairs, it will not be possible to simply look at an arbitrary `DWORD` and tell if it is a valid code point.

Comment: UTF-32 doesn't use surrogate pairs.

Comment: How are you receiving this bad data? If you're reading it in with the `Encoding` class, these characters should be removed by default.

Comment: Related to @Porges' question, if it's your code that creates strings from the source (e.g. file, network, large database field) then it could be possible to push the logic further down and deal at an earlier stage with potentially better throughput.

Comment: Thanks. It's already pushed as far forward as possible, up against a framework interface. That leaves me without full control over the strings' provenance, so I can't escape planning for the possibility of crummy input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like the only way to do it is 'manually' like you've done. Here's a version that gives the same results as yours, but is a bit faster (about 4 times over a string of all `chars` up to `char.MaxValue`, less improvement up to `U+10FFFF`) and doesn't require `unsafe` code. I've also simplified and commented my `IsCharacter` method to explain each selection:

```
static string ReplaceNonCharacters(string aString, char replacement)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(aString.Length);
    for (var i = 0; i < aString.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsSurrogatePair(aString, i))
        {
            int c = char.ConvertToUtf32(aString, i);
            i++;
            if (IsCharacter(c))
                sb.Append(char.ConvertFromUtf32(c));
            else
                sb.Append(replacement);
        }
        else
        {
            char c = aString[i];
            if (IsCharacter(c))
                sb.Append(c);
            else
                sb.Append(replacement);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

static bool IsCharacter(int point)
{
    return point < 0xFDD0 || // everything below here is fine
        point > 0xFDEF &&    // exclude the 0xFFD0...0xFDEF non-characters
        (point & 0xfffE) != 0xFFFE; // exclude all other non-characters
}
```

Comment: I just tried this. The output is identical to the input, invalid points and all.

Comment: Just did some more tests. It seems that the UTF-16 Encoding replaces broken codepoints, but doesn't deal with "non-characters". Interesting!

Comment: The problem isn't broken surrogates, it's full codepoints that are defined as non-character. U+FFFF, for example.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar performance improvement on my data. Thanks!

Comment: You've a bug, in that it's xxFFFF and xxFFFE that are the non chars. You catch this but incorrectly coment when you say U+FFFE is not a non-character, though it is, and you allow U+FFEF explicitly, but shouldn't have to. You can combine these into the same check as both match the test `(point & 0xFFFE) == 0xFFFE` and no other points do.

Comment: @JonHanna: Hence the slightly confused comments! I must have originally typoed FFFE as FFEF - and the tests were only going up to `char.MaxValue` and not `U+10FFFF`. Thanks for pointing this out. @Sean U: I've updated the code to fix this, and tested it over the entire range.

Comment: I've an approach that should be faster that uses a quarter meg of data, and another that should be faster though not as fast as that which uses considerably less, but they need some preparation. I'll see if I can add them later.

Comment: My idea for a faster one proved about equal, so so much for that.

Answer (score 3):

I went ahead with the solution hinted at in the edit.

I couldn't find an easy-to-use list of valid ranges in the Unicode space; even the official Unicode character database was going to take more parsing than I really wanted to deal with.  So instead I wrote a quick script to loop over every number on the range [0x0, 0x10FFFF], convert it to a `string` using `Encoding.UTF32.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(code))`, and try `.Normalize()`ing the result.  If an exception is raised, then that value is not a valid code point.

From those results, I created the following function:

```
bool IsValidCodePoint(UInt32 point)
{
    return (point >= 0x0 && point <= 0xfdcf)
        || (point >= 0xfdf0 && point <= 0xfffd)
        || (point >= 0x10000 && point <= 0x1fffd)
        || (point >= 0x20000 && point <= 0x2fffd)
        || (point >= 0x30000 && point <= 0x3fffd)
        || (point >= 0x40000 && point <= 0x4fffd)
        || (point >= 0x50000 && point <= 0x5fffd)
        || (point >= 0x60000 && point <= 0x6fffd)
        || (point >= 0x70000 && point <= 0x7fffd)
        || (point >= 0x80000 && point <= 0x8fffd)
        || (point >= 0x90000 && point <= 0x9fffd)
        || (point >= 0xa0000 && point <= 0xafffd)
        || (point >= 0xb0000 && point <= 0xbfffd)
        || (point >= 0xc0000 && point <= 0xcfffd)
        || (point >= 0xd0000 && point <= 0xdfffd)
        || (point >= 0xe0000 && point <= 0xefffd)
        || (point >= 0xf0000 && point <= 0xffffd)
        || (point >= 0x100000 && point <= 0x10fffd);
}
```

Note that this function isn't necessarily great for general-purpose cleanup, depending on your needs.  It does not exclude unassigned or reserved code points, just ones that are specifically designated as 'noncharacter' (edit: and some others that Normalize() seems to choke on, such as 0xfffff).  However, these seem to be the only code points that will cause `IsNormalized()` and `Normalize()` to raise an exception, so it's fine for my purposes.

After that, it's just a matter of converting the string to UTF-32 and combing through it.  Since `Encoding.GetBytes()` returns a byte array and `IsValidCodePoint()` expects a UInt32, I used an unsafe block and some casting to bridge the gap:

```
unsafe string ReplaceInvalidCodePoints(string aString, char replacement)
{
    if (char.IsHighSurrogate(replacement) || char.IsLowSurrogate(replacement))
        throw new ArgumentException("Replacement cannot be a surrogate", "replacement");

    byte[] utf32String = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(aString);

    fixed (byte* d = utf32String)
    fixed (byte* s = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(new[] { replacement }))
    {
        var data = (UInt32*)d;
        var substitute = *(UInt32*)s;

        for(var p = data; p < data + ((utf32String.Length) / sizeof(UInt32)); p++)
        {
            if (!(IsValidCodePoint(*p))) *p = substitute;
        }
    }

    return Encoding.UTF32.GetString(utf32String);
}
```

Performance is good, comparatively speaking - several orders of magnitude faster than the sample posted in the question.  Leaving the data in UTF-16 would presumably have been faster and more memory-efficient, but at the cost of a lot of extra code for dealing with surrogates.  And of course having `replacement` be a `char` means the replacement character must be on the BMP.

**edit:** Here's a much more concise version of IsValidCodePoint():

```
private static bool IsValidCodePoint(UInt32 point)
{
    return point < 0xfdd0
        || (point >= 0xfdf0 
            && ((point & 0xffff) != 0xffff) 
            && ((point & 0xfffe) != 0xfffe)
            && point <= 0x10ffff
        );
}
```

Comment: There is a designated code point for unknown characters which you should be replacing with, at least as the default replacement character; U+FFFD.

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need unsafe code; you can use [`BitConverter.ToUInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint32.aspx) to convert bytes in an array to `UInt32`s.

Comment: Yes, but that creates yet another copy of the data.

Comment: "I couldn't find an easy-to-use list of valid ranges in the Unicode space". You want to look-up non characters in the Unicode glossary, or for a more detailed (and interesting) exploration, §16.7 of the spec http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch16.pdf

Comment: In the edited concise version of `isValidCodePoint()` the `((point & 0xffff) != 0xffff)` is not necessary as `((point & 0xfffe) != 0xfffe)` catches both `0xFFFE` and `0xFFFF`.

Comment: @PatrickSchlüter Yes. Here we come to the point where minimizing instruction count and writing readable code must part ways.

Comment: If required `((point & 0xfffe) != 0xfffe) /* Catches also 0xFFFF */`, but it's quite obvious for someone used to embedded programming where bit masking is very common.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char%28v=vs.90%29.aspx should have the information that you are looking for when referring to the list of valid/invalid code points in C#. As to how to do it, it would take me a bit to formulate a correct response. That link should help you get started though.

Comment: I don't see the valid / invalid code point list anywhere in those docs - could you point us to it? Thanks

Comment: Look near the top of the page under where it says "Remarks" and it states:

_"The .NET Framework uses the Char structure to represent a Unicode character. The Unicode Standard identifies each Unicode character with a unique 21-bit scalar number called a code point, and defines the UTF-16 encoding form that specifies how a code point is encoded into a sequence of one or more 16-bit values. Each 16-bit value ranges from hexadecimal 0x0000 through 0xFFFF and is stored in a Char structure. The value of a Char object is its 16-bit numeric (ordinal) value."_

Comment: OK, but the problem here is that `String.Normalise` is rejecting ranges 0xfdd0-ef and 0xfffe-f as invalid code points. That's the information we wanted and I don't see that on the `System.Char` page.

Answer (score 0):

I like Regex approach the most

```
public static string StripInvalidUnicodeCharacters(string str)
{
    var invalidCharactersRegex = new Regex("([\ud800-\udbff](?![\udc00-\udfff]))|((?<![\ud800-\udbff])[\udc00-\udfff])");
    return invalidCharactersRegex.Replace(str, "");
}
```

Comment: Over the time since I first asked this question, I've completely moved away from using regex for these kinds of character-stripping jobs. Using regex can save some keystrokes, but in practice it ends up being less readable, harder to debug, and less performant.

Comment: @SeanU That's a valid point. I've provided Regex solution just for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way if you are on .Net core 3+.

```cs
public string FixInvalidCodePoints(string s)
{
    return string.Join(string.Empty, s.EnumerateRunes().Select(r => r.ToString()));
}
```

Invalid surrogate pairs will be replaced with the `Rune.ReplacementChar`, which is U+FFFD '�'.

Example:

```cs
FixInvalidCodePoints("Hello\ud800world!"); //returns "Hello�world!"
```

You can easily remove these replacement characters if you prefer to.